# How to break lines javascript (Form That Generates HTML Codes)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, generator

The code below is a form that generates html codes
I want each field to be on a separate line in the "Post text" field

Current output:

```
<div>texthere</div><script>texthere</script><style>texthere</style>
```

Expected output:

```
<div>texthere</div>
<script>texthere</script>
<style>texthere</style>`
```

```js
function submitted() {
  var formValue0 = '<div>' + document.getElementsByName("content")[0].value + '</div>';
  var formValue1 = '<script>' + document.getElementsByName("content")[1].value + '<\/script>';
  var formValue2 = '<style>' + document.getElementsByName("content")[2].value + '</style>';
  document.getElementsByName("content")[3].value = formValue0 + formValue1 + formValue2;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return submitted()">
  Field 1:<br><input type="text" name="content"><br> 
  Field 2:<br><input type="text" name="content"><br> 
  Field 3:<br><input type="text" name="content"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="DONE"><br><br> 
  
  Post text:<br><textarea name="content" style="height:200px"></textarea>
</form>
```

You can use this code for several things and speed up your work with repeated codes like a custom post that would have to edit the html manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use new line character `\n` like this -

```js
function submitted() {
   var formValue0 = '<div>'+ document.getElementsByName("content")[0].value +'</div>\n';
   var formValue1 = '<script>'+ document.getElementsByName("content")[1].value +'<\/script>\n';
   var formValue2 = '<style>'+ document.getElementsByName("content")[2].value +'</style>\n';
   document.getElementsByName("content")[3].value = formValue0+formValue1+formValue2;
   return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return submitted()"> 
  Field 1:<br><input type="text" name="content"><br>
  Field 2:<br><input type="text" name="content"><br>
  Field 3:<br><input type="text" name="content"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="DONE"><br><br> 
  Post text:<br><textarea name="content" style="height:200px"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: @gaetanoM here as per requirement output is in text field so we've to use new line character, `br` can be used when we've to set html